# Juno keeps booting into a blank screen

Tags: boot, greeter, release-juno, grub, nvidia

I've got an new installation of Juno, but since I installed the proprietary nvidia driver 396, Juno goes black/blank after the initial splash screen. Loki functioned fine.

The odd thing is, that after several hard resets Juno does show the greeter from time to time - it seems very random.

I've tried different commands to modify the boot from Grub, but nothing has helped this far.

Does anybody have a solution to get past the blank screen when I wan't to use the nvidia-driver, or any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: when the black screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter text mode. You can login from there. Sometimes it will show the greeter and work. When it does, update your system and see if it persists.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! See my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues can be fixed by upgrading the nvidia driver to version 410.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to uninstall the nvidia drivers, see if the nouveau open source drivers works instead

Ctrl+Alt+F1 then `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`

maybe have a look there as well : [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't bring the console forth. With the nouveau driver installed, the greeter shows as expected (though the resolution is off).
The only way I found, to get the computer to boot, is to turn it on and hard reset it until the greeter finally shows.
I modified my question, as I wan't to use the Nvidia driver.